# How to paginate with django-rest-framework and ng-admin

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework, ng-admin

Sorry if it is a silly question since it is covered in the documentation, but I can't make it work (I am new to AngularJS).

I am trying to write an interface to my database using ng-admin on top of a django-rest-framework. The problem is that the default pagination in ng-admin is like `_page=1&_perPage=30` while in django-rest-framework it's `?limit=30&offset=1`. So when ng-admin tries to GET it, it recives a `301` response. In the documentation it says:

> For instance, to use offset and limit instead of _page and _perPage across the entire application, use the following code:
>
> ```
> myApp.config(['RestangularProvider', function(RestangularProvider) {
>    RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, what, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
>        if (operation == 'getList' && what == 'entityName') {
>            params.offset = (params._page - 1) * params._perPage;
>            params.limit = params._perPage;
>            delete params._page;
>            delete params._perPage;
>         }
>         return { params: params };
>     }); 
> }]);
> ```

The problem is that I don't know exactly how to incorporate this into my code, which is:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-admin']);
myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', function (nga) {
    var admin = nga.application('My First Admin')
        .baseApiUrl('http://localhost:8000/CSP_site/'); 
    var algae = nga.entity('algae');
    algae.listView().fields([
        nga.field('name'),
        nga.field('id'),
    ]);
    admin.addEntity(algae);
    nga.configure(admin);
}]);
```

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-admin']);
myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', 'RestangularProvider', function (nga, RestangularProvider) {
    var admin = nga.application('My First Admin')
        .baseApiUrl('http://localhost:8000/CSP_site/'); 
    var algae = nga.entity('algae');
    algae.listView().fields([
        nga.field('name'),
        nga.field('id'),
    ]);
    admin.addEntity(algae);
    nga.configure(admin);

    RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, what, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
        if (operation == 'getList' && what == 'algae') {
            params.offset = (params._page - 1) * params._perPage;
            params.limit = params._perPage;
            delete params._page;
            delete params._perPage;
        }
        return { params: params };
    }); 
}]);
```

Added `RestangularProvider` in the second index of the array, which injects it as the second parameter in the `.config` function.

The rest is copy paste except `what == 'entityName'`, it became `what == 'algae'` as `algae` is the entity you added above.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, but unfortunately it is still trying to GET _page _perPage... don't know why!!

    Django version 1.11, using settings 'CSP.settings'
    Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    [02/Jan/2018 02:30:57] "GET /CSP_site/algae?_page=1&_perPage=30&_sortDir=DESC&_sortField=id HTTP/1.1" 301 0

Any suggestion?

Comment: Oh that's probably because of the `if` condition. I updated the answer, check the last couple of lines.

Comment: Oh! I see... Thanks! I think I understand what the problem was! Now there is something else... Still 301 but because a diferent reason. GET /CSP_site/algae?_page=1&_perPage=30&_sortDir=DESC&_sortField=id HTTP/1.1" 301 0 there is a `/` missing after algae... after a few trials the best I coudl get is GET /CSP_site/algae%2F?_sortDir=DESC&_sortField=id&limit=30&offset=0 HTTP/1.1  any idea how to add the `/` after algae in the request?

Comment: hmmm, can't you add a `/` to the URL you're requesting.. like `<a href="/CSP_site/algae/">URL<a/>`?

Comment: Thanks, but I read a few docs, and I think I have to fix it from the djang-rest router site...
Thanks again for your help